# Tkinter не меняет текст Label

Tags: python, tkinter

Label ( справа 2 окна ) не меняются после выбора RadioButton. Как исправить?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

w = Tk()

r1=Radiobutton(text='Київ')
r1.place(x=20, y=20)
r2=Radiobutton(text='Харків')
r2.place(x=20, y=60)
r3=Radiobutton(text='Одеса')
r3.place(x=20, y=100)

var=IntVar()
r1=Radiobutton(text='Київ', variable=var, value=1)
r1.place(x=20, y=20)
r2=Radiobutton(text='Харків', variable=var, value=2)
r2.place(x=20, y=60)
r3=Radiobutton(text='Одеса', variable=var, value=3)
r3.place(x=20, y=100)


Lbl1=Label(relief=SUNKEN)
Lbl1.place(x=100, y=20, width=160)
Lbl2=Label(relief=SUNKEN, bg='white', justify=LEFT)
Lbl2.place(x=100, y=60, width=200, height=100)

def btn_click():
    if var.get()==1:
        Lbl1['text']="Київ"
        Lbl2['text']="Місто засноване у V столітті\n Кількість населення - 2904000.\nПлоща - 847,67 кв. км."
    if var.get()==2:
        Lbl1['text']="Харків"
        Lbl2['text']="Місто засноване у 1654 р.\n Кількість населення - 1444000.\nПлоща - 350 кв. км."
    if var.get()==3:
        Lbl1['text']="Одеса"
        Lbl2['text']="Місто засноване у 1415 р.\n Кількість населення - 1012000.\nПлоща - 162,42 кв. км."


r1=Radiobutton(text="Київ", variable=var, value=1, command=btn_click)
r2=Radiobutton(text="Харків", variable=var, value=2, command=btn_click)
r3=Radiobutton(text="Одеса", variable=var, value=3, command=btn_click)


w.geometry("600x600")
w.title("Найбільші міста України")

w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавишь атрибут "command" в твои виджеты, и всё. Только в атрибуте command напиши =btn_click . Удачи!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

w = Tk()
def btn_click():
    if var.get()==1:
        Lbl1['text']="Київ"
        Lbl2['text']="Місто засноване у V столітті\n Кількість населення - 2904000.\nПлоща - 847,67 кв. км."
    if var.get()==2:
        Lbl1['text']="Харків"
        Lbl2['text']="Місто засноване у 1654 р.\n Кількість населення - 1444000.\nПлоща - 350 кв. км."
    if var.get()==3:
        Lbl1['text']="Одеса"
        Lbl2['text']="Місто засноване у 1415 р.\n Кількість населення - 1012000.\nПлоща - 162,42 кв. км."
r1=Radiobutton(text='Київ')
r1.place(x=20, y=20)
r2=Radiobutton(text='Харків')
r2.place(x=20, y=60)
r3=Radiobutton(text='Одеса')
r3.place(x=20, y=100)

var=IntVar()
r1=Radiobutton(text='Київ', variable=var, value=1, command=btn_click)
r1.place(x=20, y=20)
r2=Radiobutton(text='Харків', variable=var, value=2, command=btn_click)
r2.place(x=20, y=60)
r3=Radiobutton(text='Одеса', variable=var, value=3, command=btn_click)
r3.place(x=20, y=100)


Lbl1=Label(relief=SUNKEN)
Lbl1.place(x=100, y=20, width=160)
Lbl2=Label(relief=SUNKEN, bg='white', justify=LEFT)
Lbl2.place(x=100, y=60, width=200, height=100)




r1=Radiobutton(text="Київ", variable=var, value=1, command=btn_click)
r2=Radiobutton(text="Харків", variable=var, value=2, command=btn_click)
r3=Radiobutton(text="Одеса", variable=var, value=3, command=btn_click)


w.geometry("600x600")
w.title("Найбільші міста України")

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык